# ¿Por qué el método de solicitud SpringMVC 'GET' no esta soportado?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring

**Es el siguiente error:**

*Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]*

***El controlador***

```
@Controller
public class NoticiaControlador {

    @Autowired
    private NoticiasServicesAPI noticiasServicesAPI;

    @RequestMapping("/noticia")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("list", noticiasServicesAPI.getAll());
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/noticia/crear/{id}") 
    public String crear(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        if (id != null && id != 0) {
            model.addAttribute("noticia", noticiasServicesAPI.get(id));
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("noticia", new Noticias());
        }
        return "crearNoticia";
    }

    @PostMapping("/noticia/crear")
    public String registro(Noticias noticias, ModelMap modelo) { // String imagen
        noticiasServicesAPI.save(noticias);
        return "index";
    }
```

y en el navegador me sale

`There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'GET' not supported`

Comment: Normalmente `@RequestMapping()` sin más se usa a nivel de clase para indicar una parte de la ruta común a todos los métodos, pero si la usas en uno de los métodos al menos deberías indicarle con qué verbo se consumirá dicho endpoint: `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: ¿Qué URL has usado?

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el código no has colocado correctamente las anotaciones, las anotaciones de la clase deben de ser `@RestController` y `@RequestMapping("/noticia")`, después para tener el `GET` en la ruta `/noticia` anotas el método con  `@GetMapping()` y lo dejas vacío para indicar que utilice la ruta del controlador.

Al tener `@RequestMapping("/noticia")` en el controlador todos los métodos heredaran ese prefijo lo que hace innecesario agregar`/noticia` a los métodos, sino quedaría la ruta por ejemplo: `/noticia/noticia/crear/{id}`.

La clase con las correcciones quadria:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/noticia")
public class NoticiaControlador {

    @Autowired
    private NoticiasServicesAPI noticiasServicesAPI;

    @GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("list", noticiasServicesAPI.getAll());
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/crear/{id}") 
    public String crear(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        if (id != null && id != 0) {
            model.addAttribute("noticia", noticiasServicesAPI.get(id));
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("noticia", new Noticias());
        }
        return "crearNoticia";
    }

    @PostMapping("/crear")
    public String registro(Noticias noticias, ModelMap modelo) { // String imagen
        noticiasServicesAPI.save(noticias);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Ahora, hay algunos puntos que según las buenas practicas no están correctamente aplicados en el servicio, porque no estas respetando la utilidad de las acciones `GET y POST` con respecto a la URL porque estas describiendo la acción en la ruta `/crear` cuando la debe de marcar el `POST` únicamente, porque `/crear/{id}` no es intuitivo para pensar que buscas una noticia por id.

Las rutas correctas deberían ser:

GET   /noticias       : Listar todas las noticias
GET   /noticias/{id}  : Buscar noticia por id
POST  /noticias       : Crear una nueva noticia

La clase quedaría:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/noticias")
public class NoticiaControlador {

    @Autowired
    private NoticiasServicesAPI noticiasServicesAPI;

    @GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("list", noticiasServicesAPI.getAll());
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/noticias/{id}") 
    public String crear(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        if (id != null && id != 0) {
            model.addAttribute("noticia", noticiasServicesAPI.get(id));
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("noticia", new Noticias());
        }
        return "crearNoticia";
    }

    @PostMapping("/noticias")
    public String registro(Noticias noticias, ModelMap modelo) { // String imagen
        noticiasServicesAPI.save(noticias);
        return "index";
    }
}
```